# See dependency graph within npm module

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies

Is there an NPM module that can show the dependencies between individual JS files within a module?

Suppose I have 20 JS files in my own NPM module; I'd like to see the dependency tree between my 20 JS files.

Comment: You know you wouldn't be sure there's no other dependency, as the imports are dynamically resolved, right ? (not pretending a graph of the *obvious* dependencies wouldn't make sense)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  A trail through a dependency starts with a `require()` statement.  Simply following them recursively is a relatively trivial problem.  I'm also excluding dependencies from package.json, e.g, `require('some-module-from-npmjs.org')` will be thrown away whereas `require('./utils/calculator.js')` will be followed.

Comment: I mean it's legit to do `let randomModule = require(names[Math.random()*names.length|0]);`. Or something more useful but still dynamic. Of course there are some obvious dependencies, but, but also non obvious ones.

Comment: Ah, true.  I hadn't thought about that.  Let's assume that all `require()` statements are fully "knowable": `require('./util/calculator.js')`.

Comment: Then I guess a tool like https://github.com/pahen/madge would work

Comment: Make that an answer and I will mark it as such.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some tools are available to graph the obvious dependencies (the ones you can guess from a static analysis).

See for example [MaDGe - Module Dependency Graph](https://github.com/pahen/madge)

Comment: I made myself a convenience wrapper around this great tool to quickly open a dependency graph image from the CLI and delete it afterward: [gist](https://gist.github.com/lleaff/6e7648ebbe1b06c647b7656264f2ee93)